# Duvida Php htmlentities

Tags: php, htmlentities

Isto é mera vontade de aprender, eu coloquei em produção um site que andava a trabalhar já a algum tempo. e reparei que o 'utf8_encode' funcionava no localhost mas não funciona em produção agora. Implementei o htmlentities e o resultado foi inverso, no localhost desapareceu a data e na net está perfeito. Alguém me consegue explicar o porquê?

À esquerda é no remote server e à direita é no local: Apesar do script usado ser igual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

assim fica coreto na net:

```
<div id="news">
        <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
        <div><h2><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></h2><br><span id="date">Publicado 
                <?php
                    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8', 'Portuguese_Brazil');
                    //setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
                    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

                    $uppercaseMonth = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B'));
                    echo htmlentities(strftime( '%a, '.$uppercaseMonth.' %d de %Y'/* - %H:%M'*/, $article['article_timestamp']));
                ?></span><p><?php echo $article['article_content']; ?><br><br><span id="print"><a onclick="javascript:window.print();" href="#">Imprimir</a></span><span id="link"><a href="#">Enviar link</a></p></div>
                <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

assim fica correto no local:

```
<div id="news">
        <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
        <div><h2><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></h2><br><span id="date">Publicado 
                <?php
                    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8', 'Portuguese_Brazil');
                    //setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
                    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

                    $uppercaseMonth = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B'));
                    echo utf8_encode(strftime( '%a, '.$uppercaseMonth.' %d de %Y'/* - %H:%M'*/, $article['article_timestamp']));
                ?></span><p><?php echo $article['article_content']; ?><br><br><span id="print"><a onclick="javascript:window.print();" href="#">Imprimir</a></span><span id="link"><a href="#">Enviar link</a></p></div>
                <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: posta o trecho de código assim fica melhor de te dar um feedback

Comment: Já está, só muda a linha do echo para a data.ObgadO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo pouco que sei sobre o assunto, penso que tem a ver com a versão PHP do servidor que possui online e no localhost, e é explicado [aqui](http://pt1.php.net/htmlentities), em que se tiver PHP com versão inferior a 5.4 os caracteres por defeito<sup>(1)</sup> são ISO-8859-1, entre 5.4 e 5.6 são UTF-8 e só nas versões superiores a 5.6 é que o PHP usa os valores indicados no `setlocale()` ou no `default_charset` do `php.ini`.

Uma possível solução para deveria indicar qual o argumento de codificação no

```
htmlentities(strftime( '%a, '.$uppercaseMonth.' %d de %Y'/* - %H:%M'*/, $article['article_timestamp']), "UTF-8");
```

<sup>(1) O termo "por defeito" significa "por padrão", "pré definido".</sup>